# Django: how can I automatically generate and cache my urls.py?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-urls

My project's URLs are automatically generated in urls.py using a `for` loop (the URLs look like `AppName/ViewName`). According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request), urls.py is loaded upon every request. This appears to be slowing my site down since it requires a bunch of introspection code, so I want to generate the URLs less frequently. I could of course manually run a script to re-generate urls.py (or a file imported by urls.py) as needed, but would prefer if it happened automatically as part of project validation/startup (like the server starting up or the database being synced). I'm open-sourcing this project, and many people will be running it on their own servers, so I want to do this in a robust way. Any recommendations?

Comment: How frequently do the urls change? If it isn't often, I.e., if the urls are not generated based on database contents, I think leaving it as a utility you can run on demand, manually, makes sense.

Comment: @WadeWilliams: they don't change that often, just when someone creates a new app or view function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs do not say what you claim they do (or rather, you're reading too much into a phrase which only means "loads that Python module (if it has not already been loaded)".

Generally, the only things that happen on every request are running the middleware and the specific view code associated with that request. Even then, nothing is reloaded on every request. URLs, like all Python code, is only loaded when a new process is started, and when that happens depends on your server setup. Your problem is elsewhere: you should profile your application carefully to find out exactly where.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can look for django-json-rpc where author has realized url-generating via decorators. There are main controller which receive all requests and urls dict `{'pattern': method}`. urls dict filled automatically by decorators like `@jsonrpc_method` which receive a function and put them to urls.
I think it must run faster than the `for` and I believe that this approach will be able to apply for django.urls